# How to create and initialize an array in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

I just switched from MATLAB to visual basic, and need to know how to fill an array using a for loop. This is what I have in visual basic but it's giving me an error.  Also if someone could suggest a more efficient way of filling an array, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim x(10) As Integer
        For i = 1 To x.Length
            x(i) = i
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(x)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in .NET (including C# and VB.NET) are indexed from `0...Length-1`, whereas VB6 and VBA are indexed from `1...Length`.

Change your for-loop to this:

```
For i = 0 To x.Length - 1
```